# Matching Strings To Their Abbreviations

Tags: c++, string, match

I'm working on a problem where I have two input files with the names of airports. Each airport has a standardized abbreviation such as San Francisco (SFO) and Los Angeles (LAX)

The first input file uses these abbreviations, and the second file uses the city names.

I'm looking for an elegant solution rather than using `std::string.compare()` with 30 different if-else conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(computer_science)) each abbreviation to their full name using [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) (the latter being faster but needs more memory)

```
// Init map
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> airports = {
    { "SFO", "San Francisco" },
    { "LAX", "Los Angeles"   }
};

// Add new airports
airports["DEN"] = "Denver";

bool cmpAirports(const std::string &abbr, const std::string &fullname)
{
    auto fname = airports.find(abbr);
    if (fname == airports.end())
        return false; // No airport with such abbreviation found
    return fname->second == fullname;
}
```